# How to convert data fetched from a proxy server into javaScript processable data in the frontend React App. JSON,parse() did not work

Tags: json, parsing, proxy

In the proxy server in app.get() I used res.send() and in the frontend I receive data that can not be parsed. There is a json file in the proxy server where I read from

Comment: How will someone answer your question when you are the only one who knows what you are talking about? Please share some code and explain the issue, so someone who is going to see the problem for the first time can understand something.

Comment: componentDidMount() {  // function call after component rendered to the DOM

    fetch("/search")    // Fetching from the proxy server which reads from a json file
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
      this.setState({
          fromServer: result.serverMessage    //updating the state
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }

Comment: componentDidMount() {  // function call after component rendered to the DOM

    fetch("/search")    // Fetching from the proxy server which reads from a json file
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
      this.setState({
          fromServer: result.serverMessage    //updating the state
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }
//  I can not process the array 'this.state.fromServer'   using map() or filter() because this.state.fromServer is a text

Comment: Please delete your comments and [edit] the question to add the code there and format it as code so that it's readable. You also haven't tagged a language on your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.